# graphics artifacts (white horizontal lines) at xmonad

Tags: xmonad

I have strange graphics artifacts (white horizontal lines) at xmonad.

They are reproducible at wide number of applications (firefox, telegram, keepassxc and so on).

For some apps (like google chrome) everything is fine

Also, I don't have any kind of artifacts at all in XFCE (using xubuntu 21.10)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this in 2 ways:

- Option "TearFree" "true at /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
- using picom with glx backend